# Memory overhead of shrinking collections

Tags: java, memory, collections

I have been studying Java Collections recently. I noticed that `ArrayList`, `ArrayDeque` or `HashMap` contains helper functions which expand capacity of the containers if necessary, but neither of them have function to narrow the cap if the container gets empty.

**If I am correct, is the memory cost of references (4 byte) so irrelevant?**

Comment: Pretty much. If a collection grows so much it needs to expand, it's likely to do so again. The balance is between storage and performance.

Comment: `ArrayList` has `trimToSize()` to narrow the cap

Comment: "Cost of reference" is irrelevant; as long as it is so. Point is: if your program has to do computations on huge data; then it might no longer be irrelevant. Example: when you are asked to process millions of numbers; then it might make sense to go for an array of int; instead of using an ArrayList of Integer objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct, most of the collections have an internal capacity that is expanded automatically and that never shrinks. The exception is `ArrayList`, which has methods `ensureCapacity()` and `trimToSize()` that let the application manage the list's internal capacity explicitly. In practice, I believe these methods are rarely used.

The policy of growing but not shrinking automatically is based on some assumptions about the usage model of collections:

- applications often don't know how many elements they want to store, so the collections will expand themselves automatically as elements are added;
- once a collection is fully populated, the number of elements will generally remain around that number, neither growing nor shrinking significantly;
- the per-element overhead of a collection is generally small compared to the size of the elements themselves.

For applications that fit these assumptions, the policy seems to work out reasonably well. For example, suppose you insert a million key-value pairs into a `HashMap`. The default load factor is 0.75, so the internal table size would be 1.33 million. Table sizes are rounded up to the next power of two, which would be `2^21` (2,097,152). In a sense, that's a million or so "extra" slots in the map's internal table. Since each slot is typically a 4-byte object reference, that's 4MB of wasted space!

But consider, you're using this map to store a million key-value pairs. Suppose each key and value is 50 bytes (which seems like a pretty small object). That's 100MB to store the data. Compared to that, 4MB of extra map overhead isn't that big of a deal.

Suppose, though, that you've stored a million mappings, and you want to run through them all and delete all but a hundred mappings of interest. Now you're storing 10KB of data, but your map's table of `2^21` elements is occupying 8MB of space. That's a lot of waste.

But it also seems that performing 999,900 deletions from a map is kind of an unlikely thing to do. If you want to keep 100 mappings, you'd probably create a new map, insert just the 100 mappings you want to keep, and throw away the original map. That would eliminate the space wastage, and it would probably be a lot faster as well. Given this, the lack of an automatic shrinking policy for the collections is usually not a problem in practice.